# How to reuse view model instance for destination view in a NavigationLink

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

in the code provided below I am having an issue that the `DetailViewModel` is being recreated. That happens because the `ContentView` updates, which also recreates all the `NavigationLink`s and destinations. Because of this the state within the `DetailViewModel` is reset.

This is some example code:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {

    let items = ["Item A", "Item B", "Item C"]

    @State var contentViewUpdater = 0

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button("Update ContentView: \(contentViewUpdater)") {
                    self.contentViewUpdater += 1
                }
                List(items, id: \.self) { item in
                    // How to prevent DetailViewModel from recreating after this ContentView receives an update?
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(model: DetailViewModel(item: item))) {
                        Text(item)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

final class DetailViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let item: String
    @Published var counter = 0

    init(item: String) {
        self.item = item
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: DetailViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Counter for \(model.item): \(model.counter)")
            Button("Increase counter") {
                self.model.counter += 1
            }
        }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

Here is a screenrecording of the issue. The `DetailViewModel.counter` var resets if `ContentView` updates.

[image: screenrecording]

How can you prevent the state in `DetailViewModel` from resetting when the parent view updates?

Comment: You should have `@ObjectBinding` for `DetailViewModel` somewhere, and use it for `NavigationLink` instead of creating new instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apologies, my code is adapted from yours as I've not updated to the latest beta yet, but this works for me. I've used the concept of ["Lifting State Up" from React](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html), and moved the model data into the Master view itself.

From a playground:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport


final class ItemViewModel : BindableObject {
    let willChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

    var name: String {
        willSet { willChange.send() }
    }
    var counter: Int = 0 {
        willSet { willChange.send() }
    }

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}


struct ContentView : View {
    let items = [
        ItemViewModel(name: "Item A"),
        ItemViewModel(name: "Item B"),
        ItemViewModel(name: "Item C")
    ]

    @State var contentViewUpdater = 0

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button("Update ContentView: \(contentViewUpdater)") {
                    self.contentViewUpdater += 1
                }
                List(items) { model in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(model: model)) {
                        Text(model.name)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct DetailView : View {
    @ObjectBinding var model: ItemViewModel

    var body: some View {
        let name = model.name
        let counter = model.counter
        return VStack {
            Text("Counter for \(name): \(counter)")
            Button("Increase counter") {
                self.model.counter += 1
            }
        }
    }
}


PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

[image: Screen recording from Playground]

Comment: Thank you very much for the example. It is totally clear now how I can implement this in my project. The will try it out now and see how it goes. This is really a whole new way of thinking when writing an app.

Answer (score 1):

Your views should not have to be aware of whether SwiftUI regenerates the view or not. In your case, I think you have to change the way you have laid out your model.

There's two approaches I would take in your case:

1. Have a single model that contains the data for all your items (preferred).
2. Or, if you need a different model for each item, make it so that it remains allocated at all times (without having to take into consideration the life-cycle of your views). Maybe you can use the environment object, or have an array of DetailViewModel() models held by a State variable. Remember State variables remain allocated, even when the view regenerates.

I think the first option: having a single model, is better. But to illustrate my second point, here's a possible implementation:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let model: DetailViewModel

    init(name: String) {
        self.model = DetailViewModel(item: name)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var items = [Item(name: "Item A"), Item(name: "Item B"), Item(name: "Item C")]
    @State var contentViewUpdater = 0

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button("Update ContentView: \(contentViewUpdater)") {
                    self.contentViewUpdater += 1
                }
                List(items, id: \.id) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(model: item.model)) {
                        Text(item.model.item)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

final class DetailViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let item: String
    @Published var counter = 0

    init(item: String) {
        self.item = item
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: DetailViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Counter for \(model.item): \(model.counter)")
            Button("Increase counter") {
                self.model.counter += 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I would agree with the first approach, however, that is not really possible in my case. Thanks to Kotlin Multiplatform I can reuse the code from my Android app. So basically all the business logic of my app is already written and I don't want to rewrite that as it works good for me. I will go with the second approach as that is better for my use case. The example really helped, thanks. Is the `@State` really needed for `private var items`? The value does not change, so I don't really understand that part.

Comment: If you know `items` will not change, you should be fine using a `let` instead of a `@State private var`  then.