# Push View programmatically in callback, SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

It seems to me that Apple is encouraging us to give up using `UIViewController` in SwiftUI, but without using view controllers, I feel a little bit powerless. What I would like is to be able to implement some sort of `ViewModel` which will emit events to `View`.

**ViewModel**:

```
public protocol LoginViewModel: ViewModel {
  var onError: PassthroughSubject<Error, Never> { get }
  var onSuccessLogin: PassthroughSubject<Void, Never> { get }
}
```

**View**:

```
public struct LoginView: View {
  fileprivate let viewModel: LoginViewModel
  
  public init(viewModel: LoginViewModel) {
    self.viewModel = viewModel
  }
  
  public var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      MasterView()
        .onReceive(self.viewModel.onError, perform: self.handleError)
        .onReceive(self.viewModel.onSuccessLogin, perform: self.handleSuccessfullLogin)
    }
  }

  func handleSuccessfullLogin() {
    //push next screen
  }
  
  func handleError(_ error: Error) {
    //show alert
  }
}
```

Using SwiftUI, I don't know how to push another controller if login is successful

Also, I would appreciate any advice about how to implement what I want in a better way. Thanks.

Comment: You are correct, if you have a `SwiftUI` project, IMHO you should only use a `UIViewController` if you need to use something like delegates or something *not* (yet) available in native SwiftUI. Let's start at square one; your model needs to **drive** the views, not the reverse. it likely should be a class instance that conforms to the  `ObservableObject` protocol. (Beware, this is still early beta, and has changed in beta 5.) As for the next two things? Ask one at a time. Show code. Be aware that #2 (show alert) has undergone THREE changes over these 5 betas.

Comment: Checkout SwiftUI navigation library github.com/canopas/UIPilot for easy navigation.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

I've found the answer. If you want to show another view on callback you should

1. Create state `@State var pushActive = false`
2. When ViewModel notifies that login is successful set `pushActive` to `true`

   ```
   func handleSuccessfullLogin() {
       self.pushActive = true
       print("handleSuccessfullLogin")
   }
   ```
3. Create hidden `NavigationLink` and bind to that state

   ```
   NavigationLink(destination: 
      ProfileView(viewModel: ProfileViewModelImpl()),
      isActive: self.$pushActive) {
        EmptyView()
   }.hidden()
   ```

Comment: `Text("")` added extra space in layout for me, replacing it with `EmptyView()` did the trick

Comment: I was looking for the similar answer where I had to login  the user and navigate to detail screen. Thanks...

Comment: In step 3, need to add a $ for the binding... i.e. self.$pushActive

Comment: Fantastic! had been looking for this answer for a while!

Comment: Thanks! Although this works fine, I think Apple should change SwiftUI to make this possible without needing to resort to such an unintuitive hack to open a new view programmatically.

Comment: isActive depreciated in IOS 16

Comment: how would I implement this in IOS 16 because this method is deprecated??

Comment: Is there a way to make ProfileView(viewModel: ProfileViewModelImpl()) something generic or abstract view to be decided on runtime or it has to be know at the moment of  program completion, I would like to achieve something like coordinator pattern so navigation taps would be serviced by some delegating object ?

Answer (score 14):

I'm adding some snippets here because I think it simplifies some things and makes reusing navigation links easier:

**1. Add View Navigation Extensions**

```
extension View {
    func navigatePush(whenTrue toggle: Binding<Bool>) -> some View {
        NavigationLink(
            destination: self,
            isActive: toggle
        ) { EmptyView() }
    }

    func navigatePush<H: Hashable>(when binding: Binding<H>,
                                   matches: H) -> some View {
        NavigationLink(
            destination: self,
            tag: matches,
            selection: Binding<H?>(binding)
        ) { EmptyView() }
    }

    func navigatePush<H: Hashable>(when binding: Binding<H?>,
                                   matches: H) -> some View {
        NavigationLink(
            destination: self,
            tag: matches,
            selection: binding
        ) { EmptyView() }
    }
}
```

Now, you can call on any view **(make sure they (or a parent) are in a navigation view)**

**2. Use at leisure**

```
struct Example: View {
    @State var toggle = false
    @State var tag = 0

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 24) {
                Text("toggle pushed me")
                    .navigatePush(whenTrue: $toggle)
                Text("tag pushed me (2)")
                    .navigatePush(when: $tag, matches: 2)
                Text("tag pushed me (4)")
                    .navigatePush(when: $tag, matches: 4)

                Button("toggle") {
                    self.toggle = true
                }

                Button("set tag 2") {
                    self.tag = 2
                }

                Button("set tag 4") {
                    self.tag = 4
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

as @Bhodan mentioned you can do it by changing state

Using **EnvironmentObject with SwiftUI**

1. Add UserData ObservableObject :

```
class UserData: ObservableObject, Identifiable {

    let id = UUID()
    @Published var firebase_uid: String = ""
    @Published var name: String = ""
    @Published var email: String = ""
    @Published var loggedIn: Bool = false
}
```

the `loggedIn` property will be used to monitor when a change in user logs in or out

2. Now add it as an `@EnvironmentObject` in your `SceneDelegate.swift` file in Xcode
   this just makes it so its accessible everywhere in your app

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).

        // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
        let userData = UserData()
        let contentView = ContentView().environmentObject(userData)

        // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
```

Once you make any change to the `loggedIn` property any UI that is Binded to it will respond to the true/false value change

the as @Bhodan mentioned just add this to your view and it will respond to that change

```
struct LoginView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData

var body: some View {
NavigationView {
VStack {
NavigationLink(destination: ProfileView(), isActive: self.$userData.loggedin) {
    EmptyView()
    }.hidden()
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As of beta 5, NavigationLink is the mechanism used to programmatically push views. You can see an example of it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57273717/swiftui-navigationdestinationlink-deprecated).

Answer (score 2):

[CleanUI](https://github.com/knoggl/CleanUI) makes it extremely easy.

```
import SwiftUI
import CleanUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Button(action: {
                CUNavigation.pushToSwiftUiView(YOUR_VIEW_HERE)
            }){
                Text("Push To SwiftUI View")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The github link throws a 404. Unfortunate.

Comment: It's available again

Comment: Amazing. So clean and CleanUI has a lot of other good features as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround** without creating **additional** empty views.

You can use `.disabled(true)` or `.allowsHitTesting(false)` modifiers to disable taps on NavigationLink.

> Disadvantage: You loose default button tap highlighting.

```swift
NavigationLink(destination: EnterVerificationCodeScreen(), isActive: self.$viewModel.verifyPinIsShowing) {
    Text("Create an account")
}
.allowsHitTesting(false) // or .disabled(true) 
.buttonStyle(ShadowRadiusButtonStyle(type: .dark, height: 38))
```

Comment: verifyPinIsShowing is variable with @State or simple variable