# SwiftUI ContextMenu navigation to another view

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to get a context menu to navigate to another view using the following code

```
var body: some View
{
    VStack
    {
        Text(self.event.name).font(.body)
        ...
        Spacer()
        NavigationLink(destination: EditView(event: self.event))
        {
            Image(systemName: "pencil")
        }
    }
    .navigationBarTitle(Text(appName))
    .contextMenu
    {
        NavigationLink(destination: EditView(event: self.event))
        {
            Image(systemName: "pencil")
        }
    }
}
```

The `NavigationLink` within the `VStack` works as expected and navigates to the edit view but I want to use a `contextMenu`. Although the context menu displays the image, when I tap on it it doesn't navigate to the edit view, instead it just cancels the context menu.

I am doing this within a watch app but don't think that should make a difference, is there anything special I have to do with context menu navigation?

Comment: I've had my many hours of pain this weekend trying to get navigation to work. I concluded that SwiftUI is far from finished and especially lacks & has weird bugs/side-effects with navigation.

Comment: Does it help when you embed the `VStack` in a `NavigationView`?

Comment: @meaning-matters - VStack makes no difference, I have tried numerous different ways of doing this without success, this was the cleanest to present.  Thanks for suggestion though.

Comment: I can only wish you good luck!

Answer (score 4):

I would use the `isActive` variant of NavigationLink that you can trigger by setting a state variable. [Apple documents this here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink/3364630-init)

This variant of `NavigationLink` is well fit for dynamic/programatic navigation.

Your `.contextMenu` sets the state variable to true and that activates the `NavigationLink`. Because you don't want the link to be visible, set the `label` view to `EmptyView`

Here's an example, not identical to your post but hopefully makes it clear.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var showEditView = false

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Long Press Me")
                    .contextMenu {
                        Button(action: {
                            self.showEditView = true
                        }, label: {
                            HStack {
                                Text("Edit")
                                Image(systemName: "pencil")
                            }
                        })
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Edit Mode View Here"), isActive: $showEditView) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Context Menu")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I implemented this and I can't get the NavigationLink to display the Text.  I placed a Print statement in Button(action so know that is getting triggered but still no joy.

Comment: A bit more investigation shows the issue to be EmptyView.  If I change it to          NavigationLink(destination: EditView(event: self.event), isActive: $showEditView) {Text("Edit")} it works, but obviously the whole idea of a context menu is I don't want a button shown all the time.

Comment: Where do you have the NavigationLink in the view hierarchy?  EmptyView() has worked in every example I've used but maybe its dependent on where it lives?

Comment: I am adding it into the VStack the same as your example.  The other point to note is that NavigationView is not supported on WatchOS so VStack is my top level within the View.

Comment: Referring to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57321795/552539 changing to a text label and adding .hidden()  got it working!  Thanks for the pointer in the right direction.

Comment: Great. I didn’t realize that EmptyView doesn’t work on watchOS. Nice tip about .hidden()

Answer (score 4):

In Xcode 11.4 it's now possible to do this with sensible `NavigationLink` buttons. Yay!

```swift
.contextMenu {
    NavigationLink(destination: VisitEditView(visit: visit)) {
        Text("Edit visit")
        Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
    }
    NavigationLink(destination: SegmentsEditView(timelineItem: visit)) {
        Text("Edit individual segments")
        Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this, please?  I am not having success with this in Xcode 11.4.

Comment: The code I posted there is an exact copy paste from my app. So that code is working for me. What happens when you try it?

Comment: Sorry, I figured it out.  I wasn't wrapping your NavigationLinks in a NavigationView, duh.  Thank you!

Comment: New challenge, however.  It is not working for me if the object displaying the contextMenu is itself wrapped in a NavigationLink.  That is, NavigationView { NavigationLink(destination: EmptyView()) { Text("foo").contextMenu { NavigationLink(destination: EmptyView()) { Text("bar") } } } } works when I click "foo", but not when I click "bar" in the contextMenu.

Comment: Is that your actual code? Because a destination of "EmptyView" isn't going to be much to see  You'll probably need to provide a non empty destination view.

Comment: Yes, actual code.  But same result -- failure to navigate -- when I replace EmptyView() with Text("test").

Comment: @protasm The destination needs to be a SwiftUI View file. So you need to make a DestinationView.swift file, and use destination: DestinationView()

Comment: No, same result, unfortunately, whether the destination is EmptyView(), a Text view, or a DestinationView().  The NavigationLink on the contextMenu item will not navigate to its destination if the object displaying the contextMenu is also wrapped in a NavigationLink.

Answer (score 1):

This works on Xcode 11.6

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var isActiveFromContextMenu = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                NavigationLink(destination : detailTwo(), isActive: $isActiveFromContextMenu ){
                    EmptyView()
                }
                
                List{
                    NavigationLink(destination: detail() ){
                        row(isActiveFromContextMenu: $isActiveFromContextMenu)
                    }
                    NavigationLink(destination: detail() ){
                        row(isActiveFromContextMenu: $isActiveFromContextMenu)
                    }
                    NavigationLink(destination: detail() ){
                        row(isActiveFromContextMenu: $isActiveFromContextMenu)
                    }
                }
            }       
        }   
    }    
}

struct detail: View {
    var body: some View{
        Text("Detail view")
    }
}

struct detailTwo: View {
    var body: some View{
        Text("DetailTwo view")
    }
}

struct row: View {
    
    @Binding var isActiveFromContextMenu : Bool
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack{
            
            Text("item")
            
        }.contextMenu{
            Button(action: {
                self.isActiveFromContextMenu = true
            })
            {
                Text("navigate to")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found success in masking the `NavigationLink` in the background and switching the context with a `Button` as the shortest yet simplest alternative.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isShowing = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Hello")
                .background(NavigationLink("", destination: Text("World!"), isActive: $isShowing))
                .contextMenu {
                    Button {
                        isShowing = true
                    } label: {
                        Label("Switch to New View", systemImage: "chevron.forward")
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```