# Push View Programmatically After State Variable Defined

Tags: swift, swiftui

In my UI, I have a button for users to create a new project.  When the button is tapped, I want to trigger a new view to load for the newly created project.

I understand that I can use [NavigationLink with isActive set to a state variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57321795/1720985), but the parameter that needs to be passed to the new view has not yet been defined on load (only after the project is created).  How can I prevent errors about the project entity not being defined yet?

For example:

```
struct FirstView: View {
    @State var newProject: Project = Project()
    @State var pushNewProject:Bool = false

var body: some View {
...
    .toolbar{
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing){
                Button(action: {
                    self.newProject = Project.create(context: viewContext)
                    self.pushNewProject = true
                }){
                   Text("Create Project")
                }
            }
        }// toolbar

        NavigationLink(destination:
                        ProjectSideBar(project:  self.newProject),
           isActive: self.$pushNewProject) {
             EmptyView()
        }.hidden()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your `newProject` an optional, since you don't really want the value until it's created. Then, you can use an `if let` optional binding to only return the destination to `ProjectSideBar` available if there's a value.

Here's a simplified version of your code:

```
struct Project {
    var name: String
}

struct FirstView: View {
    @State var newProject: Project?
    @State var pushNewProject:Bool = false
    
    @ViewBuilder var navDestination : some View {
        if let newProject = newProject {
            ProjectSideBar(project:  newProject)
        } else {
            EmptyView()
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button(action: {
                    self.newProject = Project(name: "test")
                    self.pushNewProject = true
                }){
                    Text("Create Project")
                }
                
                NavigationLink(destination: navDestination,
                               isActive: self.$pushNewProject) {
                    EmptyView()
                }.hidden()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ProjectSideBar : View {
    var project : Project
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(project.name)
    }
}
```

Note that I tried using an `if let` around the `NavigationLink` first, without having to do the `navDestination` computed property, but that results in a situation where there's not an animation to the new view. I believe this *used to* work, but as of iOS 15, it seems to need the `NavigationLink` in the hierarchy the whole time to get the animation.