# How can I use Navigation in alert using SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm working on a Bluetooth Application.It has onboarding and dashboard.On the Onboarding there is pairing and instructions on how to use the module, and the dashboard controls the peripheral device.So I need to unpair using an alert and navigate it to a different page called **Onboarding**.How can I navigate to a different view using an alert.

**Code Block**

```
import SwiftUI
import BLE

struct Dashboard: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var BLE: BLE
    @State private var showUnpairAlert: Bool = false
    @State private var hasConnected: Bool = false

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let defaultDeviceinformation = "01FFFFFFFFFF"

    struct Keys {
        static let deviceInformation = "deviceInformation"
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
            // MARK: - Menu Bar
            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10) {
                VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 4) {
                    Text(self.hasConnected ? "PodId \(checkForDeviceInformation())":"Pod is not connected")
                        .font(.footnote)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                    Button(action: {
                        print("Unpair tapped!")
                        self.showUnpairAlert = true
                    }) {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Unpair")
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .font(.body)
                        }
                        .frame(minWidth: 85, minHeight: 35)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .background(Color(red: 0.8784313725490196, green: 0.34509803921568627, blue: 0.36470588235294116))
                        .cornerRadius(30)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showUnpairAlert) {
            Alert(title: Text("Unpair from \(checkForDeviceInformation())"), message: Text("Do you want to unpair the current pod?"), primaryButton: .destructive(Text("Unpair")) {
                self.unpairAndSetDefaultDeviceInformation()
                }, secondaryButton: .cancel())
        }
    }

    func checkForDeviceInformation() -> String {
        let deviceInformation = defaults.value(forKey: Keys.deviceInformation) as? String ?? ""
        print("Device Info \(deviceInformation)")
        return deviceInformation
    }

    func unpairAndSetDefaultDeviceInformation() {
        defaults.set(defaultDeviceinformation, forKey: Keys.deviceInformation)
        print("Pod unpaired and view changed to Onboarding")
    }

}
```

**Thank you !!!!**

Comment: Have you seen this: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/using-an-alert-to-pop-a-navigationlink-programmatically ?

Comment: Yup @sugar2code i tried using presentation mode but that is only to dismiss the view I want to navigate to a different view

Comment: Oh I see! I think this post is similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57645518/swiftui-form-with-error-message-on-button-press-and-navigation. They have an alert to check for errors and then navigate if all is good. So you'd need to adapt the button actions, but the principle is the same I think, where you have a navigationlink in your main view, visible if some environment variable is true, and then via alert button toggle that state. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I simplified your code snapshot for demo, but think the idea would be clear

```
struct TestNavigationFromAlert: View {

    @State private var showUnpairAlert: Bool = false
    @State private var activateLink: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Your Onboarding page"), isActive: $activateLink,
                    label: { EmptyView() })

                // DEMO BUTTON - REMOVE IT
                Button(action: { self.showUnpairAlert = true }) { Text("Alert") }

                // YOUR CODE IS HERE
            }
            .alert(isPresented: $showUnpairAlert) {
                 Alert(title: Text("Unpair from \(checkForDeviceInformation())"), message: Text("Do you want to unpair the current pod?"), primaryButton: .destructive(Text("Unpair")) {
                     self.unpairAndSetDefaultDeviceInformation()
                     }, secondaryButton: .cancel())
             }
        }
    }

    func checkForDeviceInformation() -> String {
        // YOUR CODE IS HERE
        return "Stub information"
    }

    func unpairAndSetDefaultDeviceInformation() {
        // YOUR CODE IS HERE
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.activateLink = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: worked but is depracated