# How to set .red color or .destructive to a NavigationLink inside an alert?

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I want to have a Button inside an alert that lead to another view so I have to use NavigationLink instead. But I can’t set role or foreground color to NavigationLink inside the alert. How to achieve this? I want the NavigationLink color red or like the .destructive role of Button.

```
.alert(“Proceed to play?”, isPresented: $isPro) {
NavigationLink(“Play”, destination: MyPlay())
}
```

Comment: The `NavigationLink` doesn't work inside of the `alert`, though, right?

Comment: It worked except I could not modify the color.

Comment: Use button with needed style in alert and activate link by button action programmatically, like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59281485/12299030.

Comment: I would love to do that but NavigationLink() with $isActive is going to be removed within iOS 16 so want to avoid it